# Existence of infinite subset $S$ of $B_{\ell_2}$ s.t. $\|x-y\| > \sqrt{2}$ for all $x\neq y$ in $S$.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Prove that there exists an infinite subset $S$ of $B_{\ell_2}$ (unit ball of $\ell_2$) such that $\|x-y\| > \sqrt{2}$ for all $x\neq y$ in $S$.

*Attempt*. Subset $S=\{e_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, where $e_n(k)= 1$ for $n=k$ and $0$ otherwise does not work, since $\|e_n-e_m\|=\sqrt{2}$ for $n\neq m$.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you at least find two vectors with this property?

Comment: @QuantumSpace that is not difficult at all, for example $e_1$ and $-e_1$.

Comment: @MSE I never said it wasn't simple, but a good attempt should include such things. Try to find three vectors. Does this work? Great! Try four! Do you start to see a pattern? It is how I would approach this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's enough to find a family of vectors $v_n$ in $\ell_2$
such that $\langle v_m, v_n \rangle < 0$ for all $m < n$. Here is an example:

Let $v = v_0 = (1, -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{4}, \ldots, -\frac{1}{2^k}, \ldots)$, and $v_n = T^n v$, where $T$ is the right shift, that is,
$$v_n = (0,0, \ldots, 0, 1, -\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{4}, \ldots)$$
with $n$ zeroes before $1$. It is easy to see that $\langle v_m, v_n\rangle< 0 $ for all $m< n$.

Note that we cannot replace $\sqrt{2}$ with a larger value. In fact, for $n$ unit vectors in a Hilbert space, the best angle we can ask is $\arccos(-\frac{1}{n-1})$, since we have $\sum_{i,j} \langle v_i, v_j \rangle  = \|\sum v_i \|^2\ge 0$.

Comment: Indeed, your example works fine. Let me just note that the desired set is $\{\frac{v_n}{\|v_n\|}:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, since we need to have all the elements in the unit closed ball of $\ell_2$. +1

Comment: @Nikolaos Skout: Glad you like it. All the vectors have norm $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$.